# How to replace a property in a POM in a Maven/Jenkins job?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a project with client and server components. Both have their own Maven multi-module build projects.

The correct server version must be referenced in various frontend modules. To accomplish this I set a property in my client parent POM like this:

```
<properties>
  <server.version>1.2.3</server.version>
</properties>
```

Now I'd like to update the version number *in the POM* (i.e. not just injecting a different version from the command line with -D...) during/after a Jenkins build job. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Isn't that a multi module build? sounds wrong. Which version of Maven do you use?

Comment: The client is a multi-module build and the server is another separate multi-module build. They are developed independently, which is why the client needs to specify which version of the server it depends on. The property is then used in dependency entries in the version field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the `com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer` Maven plugin which works perfectly for my case. It accepts an xpath and a regex to define what to replace in an XML file.

Example plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <file>${project.basedir}/pom.xml</file>
        <xpath>/project/properties/server.version/text()</xpath>
        <token>^.*$</token>
        <value>${newServerVersion}</value>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And the plugin can be run for each affected maven module:

```
mvn --non-recursive replacer:replace -DnewServerVersion=xxxx
```

Comment: can this update a yaml file during a build process in jenkins?

Comment: @muzi haven't looked at it lately but probably not since it's for XML files

Answer (score 1):

At itembase we use Jenkins Pipeline Plugin. It comes with some useful built in functions like for example `readMavenPom` and `writeMavenPom`. So in your build pipeline you could do something like:

```
def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
//Do some manipulation
writeMavenPom model: pom
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check maven versions plugin?
(Tbe website is shutdown but the plugin page is still avaiable in [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4YoiRibQB8IJ:mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/set.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=fi))

```
mvn -DnewVersion=<version> versions:set
```

Comment: This seems to replace some versions in dependencies directly. Actually what I'm looking for is more like a search&replace of a single property in a pom.