# How to keep the comments and formatting of pom file intact while using pipeline-utility-steps

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using pipeline-utility-steps to alter the POM file in my pipeline script. It works fine and produce the required result. But it removes all the comments I have added in my POM file. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it ?

I am simply using:

```
writeMavenPom model: pom
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is reported but not solved at the moment:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41902

Either you parse the XML with another XML library like in this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20720694/6612625

recommended or you use a maven plugin like the com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin, see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37607214/6612625

I went for the latter approach and it works quite well. It works with XPath so you can address any of the elements or attributes in your POM. And it preserves your comments in the default case.

To get a overview over the syntax I recommend:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp